# Calling stored procedure, more records returned in the controller than in MySQL client

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my controller, I'm calling the following MySQL stored procedure:

```
$details['haha'] = $this->Events->query("call sp_stats_by_event2(1,1)");
```

I get the following output:

[image]

In HeidiSQL however, I get this:

[image]

The controller returns two records. The right amount of records should be what HeidiSQL returns.

Here is the SQL of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_stats_by_event2`(IN `event_id` INT, IN `user_id` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
 select `events`.`id` AS `event_id`,`laps`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
     count(`laps`.`id`) AS `lap_count`,
     sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(`laps`.`lap_time`))) AS `avg_lap_time`,
     min(`laps`.`lap_time`) AS `min_lap_time`,
     max(`laps`.`lap_time`) AS `max_lap_time`,
     sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(`laps`.`lap_time`))) AS `total_event_time` 
     from (`events` join `laps` on((`events`.`id` = `laps`.`event_id`))) 
     where events.id = event_id and laps.user_id=user_id
     group by `events`.`id`,`laps`.`user_id`;
 END
```

At no point, do I have the fields name, event_type_id, event_sub_type_id, lap_distance and lap_target, in the stored procedure's code. CakePHP must be fetching them somewhow? Probably explains why I get two records...

**Update #1**

Full code of the action

```
public function details($event_id = null, $user_id = null) {
        $details = $this->Events->find ('all')->where ( [ 
                'Events.id' => $event_id 
        ] )->contain ( [
                'EventTypes',
                'EventSubTypes',
                'VwStatsByEvents',
                'Laps' => [ 
                        'queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
                            return $q->order ( [ 
                                    'Laps.lap_order' 
                            ] );
                        },
                        'Users' => [ 
                                'queryBuilder' => function ($q) use($user_id) {
                                    return $q->where ( [ 
                                            'Users.id' => $user_id 
                                    ] );
                                } 
                        ] 
                ] 
        ] )->first();
        $details['haha'] = $this->Events->query("call sp_stats_by_event2(1,1)");        
        $this->set ( compact ( 'details' ) );
        $this->set ( '_serialize', [ 
                'details' 
        ] );
    }
```

**Update #2**

I think the fact that I go through Events for the query, I get the fields from the Events model, which explain their presence. However, none of my records from the SP are coming up however.

**Update #3**

This is the only way I've been able to get records from a SP call returned:

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$r = $conn->execute("call sp_stats_by_event2(1,1)")->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Comment: Seems there is more code somewhere which is not shown here

Comment: @mihai I just put in the entire action code.

Comment: I dont know cakephp but it seems to me that function builds an array $details  in 2 parts,merging your sp with other queries and then serialize the whole thing.

Comment: @Mihai Agreed, I'm just not sure how, or if it should even do it. There is an indirect link between Events and what the SP returns, through the field event_id. But, nothing explicitly linking anything AFAIK...